# If $n$ has $k$ distinct prime factors, then prove that totient function of n is greater than or equal to $n\cdot2^{-k}$.

Tags: number-theory

I know that totient function of $n$ is $\phi(n)=n\big(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\big)\big(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\big)...\big(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\big)$ if $p_1,p_2...p_k$ are prime factors of $n$ .But how to proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ has $k$ distinct prime factors, we have 
$$\phi(n) = n\bigg(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\bigg)...\bigg(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\bigg)$$
where $p_i \ge 2$, $\forall i \in \{1,2,...,k\}$ (since $2$ is the smallest prime number). Then, we have
$$\phi(n) = n\bigg(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\bigg)...\bigg(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\bigg) \ge n\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)...\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)  = n\cdot2^{-k}$$